# How to access map of map in yaml file with Terraform

Tags: yaml, terraform

I have a list of defined objects in a YAML file. Some of them have themselves lists of objects. I cannot find a way to iterate on those. The YAML input file looks like this:

```
vpns:
-   name: Test
    template: template_name
    ip_type: ip
    ip_remote: 1.1.1.1
    firewall_interface: vlan.xxxx
    local_ip: 2.2.2.2
    ikev2_profile: high_secure
    ipsec_profile: secure-Test
    tunnel_interface: tunnel.1
    pre_shared_key: Redacted
-   name: other_test
    template: template_name
    ip_type: ip
    ip_remote: 3.3.3.3
    firewall_interface: vlan.xxxx
    local_ip: 2.2.2.2
    ikev2_profile: high_secure
    ipsec_profile: secure-Test
    tunnel_interface: tunnel.2
    pre_shared_key: Redacted
    proxy_ids:
    -   name: smth
        local: 10.111.0.0/24
        remote: 10.0.128.0/24
        protocol_any: true
    -   name: smth_else
        local: 10.123.1.0/24
        rempote: 10.0.213.0/24
        protcol_any: true
```

Now importing the YAML file with this (the pre_shared keys are encrypted with SOPS) work well:

```
data "sops_file" "vpns" {
  source_file = var.vpn_file
}

locals {
  tunnels = yamldecode(data.sops_file.vpns.raw).vpns
}
```

But I cannot find a way to iterate on the proxy_ids. Plus, when configuring the proxy_ids, I need to access the `template` and the `name`

```
resource "panos_panorama_ipsec_tunnel_proxy_id_ipv4" "proxy_id" {
  for_each = {for e in local.tunnels:  [for proxy_id in local.tunnels[e]: proxy_id.name => proxy_id] => e}
  template     = each.tunnel.template.name
  name         = each.proxy_id.name
.......
}
```

Along with several other ways to flatten the data, but obviously without any success.

Comment: Hi! Sorry I forgot to answer but yes, thank you, I have been using this code snippet ever since :)

Comment: No problem. Glad it is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really sure what is your iteration goal, as your example is incomplete. But if you want to iterate over only those elements which have `proxy_ids`, then you can filter out them as follows into new local variable called `tunnels_with_proxy`:

```
locals {
  tunnels = yamldecode(file("vpn.yaml"))["vpns"]
  
  tunnels_with_proxy = {for idx,tunnel in local.tunnels: 
              idx=>tunnel if contains(keys(tunnel), "proxy_ids")}
}
```

Then, in your resources, you can use `for_each` only for tunnels with `proxy_ids`. Similarly, you can do local variable without `proxy_ids`. The separation of the original array into two arrays, one with and second without `proxy_ids`, will probably simply further operations on them.